# Heap corruption detected after normal block in C++

Tags: c++

I tried to debug it and think that the problem may be in the destructor, but I can't find any way to fix it.

```
class ZooAnimal
{
    char animalSpecies[22];
    char* animalName;
    double weight;
    int cageNum;
public:
    ZooAnimal();
    ZooAnimal(const ZooAnimal&);
    ZooAnimal(const char*, const char*, double, int);
    ~ZooAnimal();
    ZooAnimal& operator =(const ZooAnimal&);

};
```

Default Constructor

```
ZooAnimal::ZooAnimal()
{
    animalName = new char[strlen("Unknown") + 1];
    strcpy(animalSpecies, "Generic");
    strcpy(animalName, "Unknown");
    weight = 0.0;
    cageNum = 0;
}
```

***Destructor function***

```
ZooAnimal::~ZooAnimal()
{

    if (animalName != NULL) {
        cout << "destroying animal... " << animalName << endl;
        delete[]animalName;
    }

}
```

Second constructor

```
ZooAnimal::ZooAnimal(const char* aniName,const char* animalSpe, double we, int cageNu) {

    animalName = new char(strlen(aniName) + 1);
    strcpy(animalName, aniName);
    strcpy(animalSpecies, animalSpe);
    weight = we;
    cageNum = cageNum;
}
```

Copy constructor

```
ZooAnimal::ZooAnimal(const ZooAnimal& rhs) {
    animalName = new char(strlen(rhs.animalName) + 1);
    strcpy(animalName, rhs.animalName);
    strcpy(animalSpecies, rhs.animalSpecies);
    weight = rhs.weight;
    cageNum = rhs.cageNum;


}
```

```
ZooAnimal& ZooAnimal::operator=(const ZooAnimal& rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        if (animalName != NULL) {
            delete[] animalName;
            animalName = new char[strlen(rhs.animalName) + 1];
            strcpy(animalName, rhs.animalName);
        }

        strcpy(animalSpecies, rhs.animalSpecies);
        weight = rhs.weight;
        cageNum = rhs.cageNum;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTFQb.jpg)
make the object can show

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& cout, const ZooAnimal& rhs) {
    cout << "Name: " << rhs.animalName << endl;
    cout << "Species: " << rhs.animalSpecies << endl;
    cout << "Weight: " << rhs.weight << endl;
    cout << "Cage number: " << rhs.cageNum << endl;

    return cout;
}
```

Main function

```
int main()
{
    ZooAnimal obj2("lion","simba",16.0,2);
    cout <<obj2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your second constructor of `ZooAnimal`, surely you want to allocate an array of chars, instead of a single char? `animalName = new char(strlen(aniName) + 1);`?

Comment: IMHO, I believe that switching to `std::string` will alleviate you from dynamic memory allocation issues, as well as passing around to functions.  This small investment will produce big rewards.

Comment: Also, by switching to `std::string`, you can eliminate the C language tag because the C language doesn't have `std::string`.

Comment: Second constructor and copy constructor should have `new char[...]` instead of `new char(...)`, like you did in the assignment operator.

Comment: Did you know that if you actually used C++ classes, like `std::string`, instead of manually allocating memory for character strings, and forcing upon yourself the headache of properly managing this memory, that you don't even have to implement the copy constructor and the assignment operator, and thus eliminate one potential source of bugs? The fewer code you write, the fewer opportunities you will have for introducing inadvertent bugs. Like not correctly creating a `char` array using `new`, which is the bug in the shown code. If you used `std::string`, there wouldn't be a `new`, and no bug.